# Copy worksheets names in a column (From a loop code)

Tags: vba, excel

Someone can help me.

Have the following code to stack information from multiples worksheets into one ("database") -  (Loop)

The only thing it is not working is the last action to copy the names of the workweeks in the "Database" Column "Aw".

Macro does not bring any error but the sheet names don't appear in the column "AW"

Any suggestion?

```
Sub Update()
' Update Templates
    Dim All As Worksheet
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Update Consol
    On Error Resume Next

    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("A2:AL1048576").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Clear

    For J = 6 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(J).Activate
        Range("A2:AL2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        With Sheets("Database").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)(2)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Database.Cells(Last + 1, "AW").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = All.Name

        End With

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are setting column AW to `All.Name`, where `All` is a Worksheet object that you have never Set.  This will generate an error, but as you have `On Error Resume Next` the error will be ignored and the next Sheet will be activated.  In the same line, you are also setting the range to copy the value of All's Name to to be the size of the CopyRng range but, again, you are not Setting CopyRng anywhere.  This will also cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I removed all selections, because they didn't seem necessary):

```
Sub Update()
'Update Templates
Dim All As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim Last As Long    'Missing value
Dim CopyRng As Long 'No need for Range in this Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Update Consol
On Error Resume Next

With ActiveWorkbook 'modify
For j = 6 To .Sheets.Count
    .Sheets(j).Range("A2:AL" & _   
    .Sheets(j).Range("A2:AL2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
CopyRng = .Sheets(j).Range("A2:AL2").End(xlDown).Row - 1
All = .Sheets(j).Name
End With

    With .Sheets("Database").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)(2)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'EDIT:
        debug.print All 'check immediate window for correct string
        .Sheets("Database").Cells(Last + 1, _
         "AW").Value = All
'      .Sheets("Database").Cells(Last + 1, _
'        "AW").Resize(CopyRng).Value = All
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Didn't know what 'Last' var is for, so don't forget to address it before running the code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peter.

But still not working. Does not copy the tab name in the collumn